# Changing database in Adminer editor

Tags: php, mysql, adminer

Since the new versions of phpmyadmin no longer work for me (always times out) I am switching to Adminer. I have multiple databases within MySQL and have not found a way to switch between them using the Adminer Editor like you can using the Adminer management tool. I am trying to evaluate the editor to see if it can add any additional functional value to the management tool, but it just connects to the first database and cannot switch to another. Any tips, tricks, pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First [Download Adminer Editor](http://www.adminer.org/en/editor/) and rename rename file to `editor.php`. Then create new file `myEditor.php` with follow content

```
<?php
function adminer_object() {
  class CustomDatabase extends Adminer {
   function database() {
      return 'database'; // < YOUR DB name goes here
    }
  }
  return new CustomDatabase;
}
include __DIR__ . '/editor.php';
```

Then copy both files to server. You can read more about [how to extends Adminer and Adminer Editor](http://www.adminer.org/en/extension/) in documentation.

Comment: I'm talking about Adminer EDITOR - not the basic management tool which does allow you to switch databases. From what I've seen so far the management tool works great, but the separate 'editor.php' tool can not switch databases. .... I am logging in as root on a localhost development machine.

Comment: Actually you don't need to extend Adminer, works just fine without that. this version breaks custom themes and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Switching between databases is possible on the left-hand side of the screen in the seperate menu. I use adminer daily on servers with multiple databases effortless.

In order to do so you'll need one user that has access to all databases however.